# Please tell me how to appear markup near a specific 2D object in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am developing HTML + JS using the forge viewer of Autodesk-forge.
I am looking for a way to display text near a specific object in 2D on the viewer.
Please let me know if there is a fix for the code below, or any other way to do it.

- What I tried and result
  I practiced the contents of the following article
  https://adndevblog.typepad.com/technology_perspective/2020/12/forge-viewer-markup-along-dbid.html
  The markup could be displayed on the 3D model as expected.
  However, it was not possible to set the markup position on the 2D model.
- Code (excerpt)
  Calling part

```
      viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, () => {   
        createMarkUp(viewer, {
          icons: [
           { dbId: 11146, label: 'コメントあり', css: 'iconWarning  fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x 
              faa-flash animated' },
          ],
          onClick: (id) => {
            viewer.select(id);
          }
        }); 
      });
```

Logic part

```
   function createMarkUp(viewer, options) {
    let _group = null;
    let _button = null;
    let _icons = options.icons || [];
    let _frags = null;

    viewer._enabled = true;
    load();
    showIcons(true);

      function load() {
        const updateIconsCallback = () => {
          if (viewer._enabled) {
            updateIcons();
          }
        };
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.HIDE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        return true;
      }

      function showIcons(show) {
        const $viewer = $('#' + viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer');

        // remove previous...
        $('#' + viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer label.markup').remove();
        if (!show) return;

        // do we have anything to show?
        if (_icons === undefined || _icons === null) return;

        // do we have access to the instance tree?
        const tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
        if (tree === undefined) { console.log('Loading tree...'); return; }

        const onClick = (e) => {
          if (options.onClick)
              options.onClick($(e.currentTarget).data('id'));
        };

        _frags = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < _icons.length; i++) {
          // we need to collect all the fragIds for a given dbId
          const icon = _icons[i];
          _frags['dbId' + icon.dbId] = []

          // create the label for the dbId
          const $label = $(`
          <label class="markup update" data-id="${icon.dbId}">
              <span class="${icon.css}"> ${icon.label || ''}</span>
          </label>
          `);
          $label.css('display', viewer.isNodeVisible(icon.dbId) ? 'block' : 'none');
          $label.on('click', onClick);
          $viewer.append($label);

          // now collect the fragIds
          tree.enumNodeFragments(icon.dbId, function (fragId) {
              _frags['dbId' + icon.dbId].push(fragId);
              updateIcons(); // re-position of each fragId found
          });
        }
      }

      function getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(dbId) {
        const fragList = viewer.model.getFragmentList();
        const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3();

        // for each fragId on the list, get the bounding box
        for (const fragId of _frags['dbId' + dbId]) {
          const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3();
          fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox);
          nodebBox.union(fragbBox); // create a unifed bounding box
        }

        return nodebBox
      }

      function updateIcons() {
        for (const label of $('#' + viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer .update')) 
        {
          const $label = $(label);
          const id = $label.data('id');

          // get the center of the dbId (based on its fragIds bounding boxes)
          const pos = viewer.worldToClient(getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(id).center());
          // position the label center to it
          $label.css('left', Math.floor(pos.x - $label[0].offsetWidth / 2) + 'px');
          $label.css('top', Math.floor(pos.y - $label[0].offsetHeight / 2) +  'px');
          $label.css('display', viewer.isNodeVisible(id) ? 'block' : 'none');
        }
      }
  　}
```

- Constitution
  　　HTML+JS

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code above cannot be applied to 2D drawings as those use a different internal data structure.

With that said, you should still be able to achieve what you want because the Viewer APIs provide some utilities for 2D designs as well. For example, based on [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer), you can obtain the bounding box of a specific element in your 2D drawing like so:

```js
function getBounds2D(viewer, model, dbId) {
  const frags = model.getFragmentList();
  let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
  let boundsCallback = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback(bounds);
  let fragIds = frags.fragments.dbId2fragId[dbId]; // Find all fragments including this object's primitives
  if (!Array.isArray(fragIds)) {
    fragIds = [fragIds];
  }
  for (const fragId of fragIds) {
    // Get the actual mesh with all geometry data for given fragment
    const mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fragId);
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(mesh.geometry, viewer.impl.use2dInstancing);
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, boundsCallback); // Update bounds based on all primitives linked to our dbId
  }
  return bounds;
}
```

This will return a `THREE.Box3` structure defining the extent of the 2D primitive. From there, you could grab the center of the bounding box, project it to screen coordinates, and use the screen coords to position your HTML overlay elements, for example:

```js
const bounds = getBounds2D(viewer, viewer.model, someDbId);
const coords = viewer.worldToClient(bounds.center());
$label.css('left', Math.floor(coords.x + 'px');
$label.css('top', Math.floor(coords.y + 'px');
```

Comment: Hello, Pet. Thank you for your answer. I can solve this problem with the solution you told me.